# Does DocuSign counts expired signature request to charge account?

Tags: docusignapi

When embedded signing is used to integrate DocuSign into third party application, how does the cost charging works for the expired embedded signature request URL. Because, when an embedded signature request URL is generated, it lives for only 30 minutes and if user doesn't do anything after opening up the URL then this url returns an Event.ttl_expired. So, does this embedded signing request considered for while system counts for chargeable requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "cost charging" you mean the price you're paying for your DocuSign plan -- then, no: you should not incur any additional cost if you have to generate a new embedded signature URL when the original one has expired. In this scenario, you're not creating a brand new Envelope -- you're simply refreshing the URL that a signer can use to access an existing envelope. Since you're not creating a new Envelope, there should be no monetary cost or impact to the number of Envelopes remaining in your subscription.

That said, you will have to issue an API request to generate a new embedded signing URL, so if you're paying for a certain number of API requests per month (I'm not even sure if that's an option with DocuSign subscriptions), then this request would count against that quota.